# Could not resolve external workbook name 'excel_file_name.xlsx'. Workbook environment has not been set up

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

My Spring Boot project using Apache Poi to read data from excel file.

i use `FormulaEvaluator` to calculate the value of cell

```
FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
formulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell)
```

I get the error

> Could not resolve external workbook name
> 'excel_file_name.xlsx'. Workbook
> environment has not been set up.

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Assuming you have that other referenced workbook, how about [FormulaEvaluator.setupReferencedWorkbooks](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#setupReferencedWorkbooks-java.util.Map-) ?

Comment: yes, just because this error happen when upload file so getCachedFormulaResultType maybe the good choice

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue by using method `getCachedFormulaResultType` as the document [org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCachedFormulaResultType--)

> CellType getCachedFormulaResultType()
>
> Only valid for formula cells
>
> Returns:
> one of (CellType.NUMERIC, CellType.STRING, CellType.BOOLEAN, CellType.ERROR) depending on the cached value of the formula

i think method `evaluateFormulaCell` not work because the formular reference to another workbook